# Mysql, select id's grouped by distinct column (select all ids for each unique domain)

Tags: php, mysql, select

So I have a MySQL table:

```
Table Data:

id | domain     | title                | Full Url to Page | ... etc ...
1  | place.com  | Place Something      | http://place.com/1...
2  | place.com  | Place Something Else | http://place.com/2...
3  | place.com  | Some Other Place     | http://place.com/3...
4  | pets.com   | Cats Dogs Oh My      | http://pets.com/2....
5  | pets.com   | Bird Edition         | http://pets.com/3....
```

What I need (in PHP / JQuery) is to get an array of id's for each unique domain. So the final output that I want for the above table is:

```
$finalArray = array('place.com' => array(1, 2, 3), 'pets.com' => array(4, 5));
```

My current solution is to grab all rows ordered by domain, heres the MySQL statment:

```
SELECT `id`, `domain` FROM `gsort_linkdata` ORDER BY `domain`
```

Which returns:

```
1  | place.com
2  | place.com
3  | place.com
4  | pets.com
5  | pets.com
```

I then loop through the rows in PHP and break them into arrays. I would prefer to pull already broken up data from the database. Is that possible? Thank you!

Comment: I feel what you have is probably best since you will 1)hit the database only once, and 2)be able to create the array simply in one pass because of the ordering.

Comment: I agree. I've dealt with this same type of problem many times before--with multiple levels of nested arrays. You can't return nested arrays from SQL databases. Your solution of looping and building the response in the PHP middleware is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks guys. I just wasnt sure if I knew the best solution. I always feel that there must be something better, faster, stronger so its good to know I chose correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id`), `domain` FROM `gsort_linkdata` GROUP BY `domain`
```

(Be aware of [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).)

But because there is no way to pass an array from MySQL to PHP, you need to split up the resulting string in PHP or JS, so I think your current method is the better one. Your method is safe and really just a one-liner in PHP, anything else (including GROUP_CONCAT) is more complicated .

Comment: Ive never used group_concat I will have to play around with it thank you.

Comment: As you say I don't think this is good. You are asking the database to do hard work creating a comma-delimited string, only to split it again and have to parse the strings back into integers.

Comment: @lc. I totally agree. GROUP_CONCAT was the closest thing to what the OP asked for, given that you can't pass an array from MySQL to PHP.