# User roster, joining a table but loosing data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need some help with a query (using Laravel framework). I'm building a user roster with a few columns that incude the users ratings. Basically, it selects all the active users who have initials and joins the user ratings table to select the ratings for the respective users. The `where_in` is to select only specific ratings. My issue is on the roster, it only selects one rating, rather than all of them (if the user has more than one rating). I've also tried without the `group_by`, but then the users are duplicated on the table depending on the number of ratings they have (example: if the user has 2 ratings, their row is displayed twice on the roster).

Query:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->where('users.initials', '!=', '')
    ->left_join('user_ratings', 'user_ratings.uid', '=', 'users.uid')
    ->where_in('users_ratings.rid', array(6,17,21,20))
    ->group_by('users.uid')
    ->order_by('users.name')
    ->get();
```

Tables:

```
  Users
  =======
  uid    name 
  1      John
  2      Jeff
  3      Cathy

  Ratings
  ======
  rid   uid
  1     1
  2     1
  2     2
  3     1
  4     3
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is when you do a left_join, the result you are going to get is multiple rows. So without the group_by clause it will return all the results you want in rows, not columns, and with the group_by it will just return the first rating (which is the expected behavior).

I would suggest you just use Eloquent ORM and set up the models and their relationships (it's a lot easier and cleaner). I'm guessing user_rating is a many-to-many pivot table? In which case you would have two models User and Rating and their relationship will be has_many_and_belongs_to. Also, the naming conventions in laravel have the pivot table in alphabetical order, so it will be called "rating_user". Look here for how to set up relationships: http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#relationships

Once the models with their relationships are setup, what I would do is

`$users = User::where('initials', '!=', '')->order_by('name')->get();`

Then,

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    echo "Ratings for " .$user->name . ": ";
    $ratings = $user->ratings()->pivot()->where_in('rid', array(6,17,21,20))->get();
    foreach($ratings as $rating) {
        however you want to display the ratings here...
    }
}
```

This may not be the most efficient way, but it should get the job done given my assumptions are true.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent) reveals that the Fluent Query Builder can only do what MySQL can do, and MySQL cannot return an array to the client.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063558/mysql-select-ids-grouped-by-distinct-column-select-all-ids-for-each-unique-do) for your alternatives.

If you want Laravel to [fetch the ratings for you, you need to build a model](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#one-to-many).